# how to create log in page in android app?

Tags: android, mysql, database, authentication

I am new in android. I am developing android application for mobile. I want to save user name and password on server side when first time user use my app on mobile and also authenticate that user name and password with user name and password on my website. And if user do not registered on my website immediate signup button to redirect control to my website. I do not know how to implement this. I know its not good question. But i am in trouble. Please someone help me.

Thanks in Advance...

If someone have some code to explain me i am very thankful...

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far. Remember how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: First i have thinking to create database for username and password using sqlite. but i do not know how to authenticate username and password with user's username and password that already registered on my website.

Comment: @JohnR check out the updated answer with detailed explanation

Comment: According to you all how this question is to be asked?

Comment: Lots of people here work for money not for knowledge and to help someone. quite funny.

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) will walk you through everything you need to know about creating a registration/login authentication.

Comment: androidhive.info is not a good resource ... for example with this tutorial you'll face my favorite exception ....

Answer (score 1):

Use OAuth to securely send username & password to your server & receive back response...As Facebook, Google, Twitter are using OAuth to Authenticate Users...

```
OAUth 1.0 - http://oauth.net/
OAuth 2.0 - http://oauth.net/2/
```

OAuth 2.0 Tutorials

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/index.html

http://net.tutsplus.com/tag/oauth-2-0/

or

You can use Below steps to securely Authenticate Users in your android App with HTTP Post Request to your PHP server.

1. Create HTTP Post request & send username & password with HTTP request to your server

   ```
    public void postData() {
      // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

      try {
         // Add your data
         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "12345"));
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "12345676890"));
         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

       // Execute HTTP Post Request
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
           builder.append(line).append("\n");
       }
       builder.toString();
       //Use builder.toString() to see output

       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     }
   }
   ```
2. Receive username & password in script.php file on your server

   below code is for mysql database -

   ```
   if(isset($_POST)){
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

   //Connect to your database & check if above values exists in your user database or not     
   $host="localhost"; // Host name 
   $username="root"; // Mysql username 
   $password=""; // Mysql password 
   $db_name="test"; // Database name 
   $tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

   // Connect to server and select databse.
   mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
   mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


     // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
     $username = stripslashes($myusername);
     $password = stripslashes($mypassword);
     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
     $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
     $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and     password='$password'";
     $result=mysql_query($sql);

     // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
     $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

     // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
     if($count==1){

      //echo back the success string with code in JSON or any other format
      echo "SUCCESS:User is registered";
     }
     else {
        echo "FAILURE:Wrong Username or Password";
        }
     }
   ```
3. Parse out response from HTTP request in your Android Activity & based on response check if user is registered or not

   ```
   Parse response from this line..
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        builder.append(line).append("\n");
   }
   builder.toString();
    //Use builder.toString() to see output
   ```

Comment: I am little confused as there is no proper way of coding.

Comment: OAuth documentation - http://hueniverse.com/oauth/

Comment: Bro. simply tell me how i start first and after that what sub-sequent steps?

Comment: is it only authenticate username and password or also register new user in my database?

Comment: the above code is to authenticate username & password. Based on above procedure you send username, email & register credentials to server. PHP file on server will receive all data & store that data into mysql database & return back the response like"User Registered successfully". You can use same or separate PHP file for login & registration.

Comment: @JohnR i am happy to help you...meanwhile you can accept the answer...

Comment: I will. but first i want to implement this code.

Comment: @JohnR i agree with you. Make some modifications according to your needs like put correct database credentiations, correct server URL & beside that if you need any help, you can comment here..

Comment: Here  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "12345"));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "12345676890")); you are passing values in usernsme and password. i have to create methods that sends username and password entered by user?

Comment: create two EditTexts one for username & one for password & one Button for login or register action. When user will tap on login or register button get values from EditTexts and then create nameValuePairs with those values entered by user

Comment: 1.Create HTTP Post request & send username & password with HTTP request to your server and 3.Parse out response from HTTP request in your Android Activity & based on response check if user is registered or not         i have to add this code in my loginActivity class?      and 2.Receive username & password in script.php file on your server    to my web server?

Comment: sorry i do not have much knowledge about this thats why lots of questions.

Comment: tell me your email & i will contact you via email...

Comment: can you help me in one link?

Comment: okk tell me your problem...

Comment: check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978275/android-login-authentication-with-remote-mysql-database