# how to create oAuth authentication login usingin android

Tags: php, android, oauth

Hello everyone I am developing an Android app for a website. I have to create a login system to the app. The client provided me with a WEB API. I have implemented the REST client for call the API get the username. In that case they have not published their users and password they want to build login under the `oAuth` Authentication flow. I have read a lot of articles regarding `oAuth` but don't understand it.

Can anyone help me clarify `oAuth` usage, please?

Comment: an android app for authentification isn't linked with the language that you use in your web site (only in the case that you make it a responsive one and use it)

Comment: you can find a lot of tutorials ( for example in youtube ) to show you how to use a database to make an authentification

Comment: you mean display the website in app?

Comment: for my first comment yes this was what i meant , and for my second com you can easily find a tuto that make an authentification android app

Comment: yes i watched and read lots of thing but i can't get good idea abouth the oAuth system..

Comment: you can read this post about oAuth system [how to create log in page in android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917620/how-to-create-log-in-page-in-android-app)

Comment: ok @YagamiLight thank you i will read it

Comment: if it solve your problem tell me i will make it as an answer